# static library linking between mismatched compilers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries

I am building a 3rd party library (ogre3d) that I will statically link against. I am using c++ visual studio 2013. I have always built 3rd party static libraries from source code and then linked against them using the same compiler including compiler version number and configuration settings to ensure compatibility.

I like the way boost generates its library filenames by including compiler version and other flag settings to make things nice and easy.

However whilst building ogre it expects you to get about 10 3rd party dependencies (admittedly only one is actually required). Whilst downloading the prebuilt binary dependencies static lib files they don't specify which compiler the lib was built with. So what's the point of supplying this? Is it wiser to get the source code and build myself? But if this dependency also has dependencies that I have to go and build then I could be doing this forever. Or are some static libraries safe to link against despite mismatched compilers? Perhaps libraries built in C (due to no name mangling?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no point of course.  The source of the dependencies is a separate download.  Probably because it doesn't change as often.

Comment: My question was more when is it safe to use prebuilt binaries if you don't know which compiler it came from compared with building it yourself from source. It isn't safe to do it with boost and ogre but it seems to be safe with free type

Comment: In general, no, you can't take a static lib created by an arbitrary, unknown tool, link against it, and expect things to work. In fact, even if the lib was generated by the same compiler you're using, there could still be issues if you use a different set of flags in your build than the library did in its. These sorts of problems are the whole reason COM was invented, and no sane person would have chosen to complicate life as much as COM does without a good reason. :)

Comment: [This article](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands) has some discussion of the issue.

Comment: You can download Ogre-Dependencies from https://bitbucket.org/cabalistic/ogredeps and build them yourself with CMake.